# What is the theoretical upper limit number of datums possible in a single Datomic database?

Tags: datomic

I am to understand that there is a hard limit on number of datums that an individual datomic database can store. What is this figure, and why is there a hard limit? Thanks

Comment: and why, pray tell, has someone deemed this question worthy of a down vote? Is it not a seriously intended question?

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be 10 billion datoms (facts) according to the Datomic discussion thread below:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datomic/iZHvQfamirI

"10 billion datoms is *not* a hard limit, but all of the reasons above you should think twice before putting significantly more than 10 billion datoms in a single database."